# IPv6 connectivity

Tags: networking, ipv6

Is IPv6 connectivity supported on the Raspberry Pi? If yes, is it enabled by default/how do I turn it on?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are no hardware limitations for IPv6 connectivity, only software must support it. On Arch distribution, IPv6 is enabled by default, so if you have a router with DHCPv6 or RA, you will automatically get connected to the IPv6 internet.

Raspbian supports IPv6, but the kernel module is not loaded by default (which is a crying shame in the wake of [recent developments](http://www.potaroo.net/tools/ipv4/index.html)). IPv6 can be enabled at run time by `modprobe ipv6` command or at boot time by appending `ipv6` to `/etc/modules`.

I would look into specific distributions' documentations to learn more about configuring IPv6 on the device.

Answer (score 3):

No, in the recommended image (the Debian one,  debian6-19-04-2012.zip), IPv6 is *not* present (neither in the kernel, nor in a module) despite what Tibor said.

```
stephane@raspberrypi:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ba:90:94  
      inet addr:192.168.2.38  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1488  Metric:1
      RX packets:1014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:69236 (67.6 KiB)  TX bytes:57486 (56.1 KiB)
```

You have to recompile the kernel.

Comment: Can anyone confirm? I recall IPv6 being available on Debian.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. I run Debian ARM on a SLUG, which run IPv6, but the Raspberry Pi doesn't.  This is really bad. :(

Answer (score 3):

The squeeze debian image, debian6-19-04-2012.zip, does not come with ipv6.

There's a beta image out that is much more recent (and behaves much better for me in several other ways too), that *does* have IPv6. This is at http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1435

Using that image, IPv6 came up automatically on boot (on my network which already has IPv6 configured).

Answer (score 3):

I just tested the wheezy version (thanks to Ben for the link) and I can confirm IPv6 is OK.
I did a fast test with "Debian wheezy+Apache2+Wordpress" and is working properly... slow... but not to bad for testing purpose.
If you like to check you can go to "http://myraspberry.farm-net.eu".
If you have a dual stack client you can view your ip addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update this answer, the issue is there are many version of Raspberry Pi and (as of today) two Raspbian (Debian) version available.
**Wheezy**
IPV6 is not active by default. You can activate with
     sudo modprobe ipv6
and ipv6 will show up on your next `ifconfig`. To make the change permanent must modify the list of modules on `/etc/modules` and append `ipv6` (this is the module name).
To support ipv6, your `/etc/networks/interfaces` file will look like:

```
iface wlan0 inet6 auto
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**Jessie**
IPV6 is active and loaded by default. No changes required.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/ modules
You must activate the ipv6 module

```
 sudo vim /etc/modules
```

and add

```
ipv6
```

then reboot your pi to activate the module

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This just duplicates part of the accepted answer.