# trying to get SSH over USB to work (Raspberry pi Zero)

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, data-transfer, usb-hub

I followed several steps to get an SSH over USB working. I followed the steps posted [here](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a).
My Raspberry Pi Zero is connected with a standard micro USB cable to my desktop computer (Ubuntu 16.04). Desktop is running the `avahi-daemon`. I used the pi usb port labelled 'data'.

My pi is booted and running. `ifconfig` shows the Raspberry pi is connected (enp0s22f2u2i1 Link encap:Ethernet). It also has an inet6 address. SSH to this i6 adress returns a `port 22: network is unreachable`. Also `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` as posted in the tutorials gives an error: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known`.

I gave the rapsberry pi an IP adress using `ifconfig enp0s22f2u2i1 192.168.1.222`. Ubuntu gives me a notification that the device is connected, however I still can't SSH to the Pi (`ssh pi@192.168.1.222`). But this time the error message is different: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.222 port 22: Connection refused`.

What else can I try to get SSH over USB to my Pi Zero working? Perhaps I do need to adjust the setting for the bonjour service (`avahi-daemon`) running on my desktop?

Comment: What is are you using on the Pi?

Comment: How are you running `ifconfig` on the Pi if the data cable is connected to another computer but you cannot connect to the Pi?  If you are running `ifconfig` on the other computer, **you didn't assign an IP to the Pi, you assigned it to the `enp0...` interface on that computer.**  That's *not* part of the Pi.  That's a USB ethernet link on the PC/laptop/whatever.  The pi is on the other end, but if you can't log into it, you can't configure the Pi side that way.

Comment: I run ifconfig on the desktop side, since that side is running the bonjour service. Basically my question boils down to how to setup the avahi-daemon, since obviously the standard configuration is not working. What is the best way to test if the mDNS is enabled on the raspberry pi side?

Comment: @MohammadAli I would like to answer, but can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Timtico I ment to say "OS" as in operating system

Comment: @MohammadAli The operating system running on the Pi is Rasbian Jessy with Pixel (kernel version 4.4)

Answer (score 1):

I am almost 100% sure that means your `ssh` is not enabled. Go to `raspi-config` and enable it from there.

Comment: the ssh was already enables. `avahi-browse`on my desktop connected to the pi shows the pi services (host name is `p`)

```Found service 'p (VNC Server)' of type '_rfb._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.1.
Found service 'p' of type '_udisks-ssh._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.1.
Found service 'p [f6:ea:85:b7:36:ba]' of type '_workstation._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

On your ubuntu machine, open the network interface settings and under ipv4 settings change the method drop-down to link-local. You should see the connection suddenly reconnect (if not, manually disable then re-enable the interface) and then the ssh will work as described.

What i havent been able to work out is how to share my internet connection from the ubuntu host to the pi

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would to is to run [`avahi-browse -art`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/avahi-browse) to see if the laptop discovered the RPi and what kind of address (IPv4 or IPv6) it has. I assume that it is IPv6, in that case you have to specify the right network interface when running the SSH client:

```
ssh -6 pi@raspberrypi.local%enp0s22f2u2i1
```

This is the flip side of IPv6 protocol: every device on the network has an IP address (yay!) but exactly because of this, `ssh` has no idea where to send the data if you specify just the address. `fe80::X:X:X` addresses are valid for every IPv6 network interface, so if your laptop has more than one, `SSH` will need an extra hint. Technically you don't really need to specify the `-6` argument, but debugging gets easier when you know exactly which protocol is concerned.

If that doesn't help, try disabling IPv6 for mDNS. Apparently, setting `publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=no` and `use-ipv6=no` in `avahi-daemon.conf` is enough, if you need IPv6 running for other purposes. Otherwise, you can disable IPv6 [completely](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29843/33476).