# Does appending ipv6 to /etc/modules enable IPv6 at boot?

Tags: raspbian, networking, ipv6

Apparently, I [can](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40/1278) [enable](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#How_do_I_enable_or_use_IPv6.3F) IPv6 in two ways. To test, I first confirm it's not enabled currently.

```
$ ping6 -c 1 ::1
socket: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I then enable it immediately

```
$ sudo modprobe ipv6
```

And `ping6 -c 1 ::1` now works. To enable it at boot, I append `ipv6` on a single line to `/etc/modules`, then reboot. However, it's unclear if IPv6 is working now.

```
$ ping6 -c 1 ::1
connect: Cannot assign requested address
```

N.B. it's a different error to the first one. If informative, the original enabling doesn't work now either.

```
$ sudo modprobe ipv6
$ ping6 -c 1 ::1
connect: Cannot assign requested address
```

How can I enable IPv6 at boot?

### EDIT

Here are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`. It's a static IP.

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.91
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: What OS? An ancient link to an answer on an obsolete OS are meaningless.

Comment: @Milliways Oops, sorry, forgot. I added the Raspbian tag. FWIW the official FAQ suggest the same thing (I edited in that link too).

Comment: Why have you put an (incorrect) ip4 static address into your file? See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Milliways I'm not sure which part you're referring to? The file looks pretty similar to your link. The `192.168.1.91` part?

Comment: That is NOT the recommended method of setting static (which I recommend against), and is there for those who insist on using Debian networking, and is conditional on disabling `dhcpcd`. But why IP4 in a question about IP6?

Comment: @Milliways Ah ok, I re-read your link in more detail. Basically, I had the current static-IP strategy set up years ago, and hadn't revisited it. I presumed that IPv4 and v6 could work concurrently as a dual stack. I figured that `sudo modprobe ipv6` allowed that to happen. IPv6 worked from `ping6`, and IPv4 was still working from my ssh session. However, IPv6 seemed to fail with the `/etc/modules` tactic. I couldn't care less about IPv6 generally, but I'm attempting to install `ejabberd`, and [apparently](https://github.com/jabber-at/ejabberd/issues/13#issuecomment-255361033) IPv6 is required.

Comment: They do work as a dual stack.  That's odd -- I just checked a pi running stock Raspbian, stock kernel, and the ipv6 module is loaded (perhaps because it is a dependency for other modules loaded because I've configured ip6tables). `ping6 ::1` works as well.  Unfortunately though [my  `/etc/network/interfaces` is only two lines](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37594/5538)  (i.e., I don't use it, but I don't recommend that either) so I can't say what would be wrong there.    You might try asking about this one on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks. It's originally a pretty old Raspbian install, which I've updated over the years, so I guess it's plausible that there are some new defaults that are different. I'll look into the different static IP config and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

As of Raspbian 8/Jessie, IPv6 is enabled in the Raspbian images right from the start. There is no need to touch any configuration.

With the `dhcpcd` client installed, IPv6 stateless address autoconfiguration (sic!) will be used with stable semantically opaque IIDs (interface identifiers). You only need a router advertising an IPv6 prefix (or several). In addition, DNS server addresses will also be autoconfigured from the router advertisements (RA). It's perfectly fine to have the RAs set M=0 and O=0, that is, no DHCPv6.